# Using DataOutputStream to save a file, the how to out write the list<String>

Tags: java, file

I want to use DataOutputStream to get a file named"saved.txt". here are the codes:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;



public class ObjectOutputStreamTest {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int number1=5;
    double number2=10.3;
    String string="a string";
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("a");

    try{
        DataOutputStream out= new DataOutputStream(new       FileOutputStream("saved.txt"));

        out.writeInt(number1);
        out.writeDouble(number2);
        out.writeBytes(string);
        out.write(list);
    } catch( IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


    }
```

But there is error at `out.write(list);`, the error is:
The method write(int) in the type DataOutputStream is not applicable for the arguments (List). So how to correct this error? Thank you for any suggestion and answers.

Comment: I suggest to use XML Serializer/Deserializer rather than using Object IO Streams.

Comment: @Glenn-- XML doesn't really seem the right choice for a text file called `saved.txt`.

Comment: dataoutput stream only handles primitive in its way.

Comment: You're writing binary to a file called `.txt`. You need to make up your mind. If you want text, you will need a text-based serializer, e.g. an XML writer, or if you want an arbtrrary text format use `PrintWriter`. If you want to write binary primitive types you can use a `DataOutputStream`, or for primitive types and objects you can use an `ObjectOutputStream`, but don't call the file `.txt.`

Answer (score 1):

[`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) is for writing values in a binary format that can be read again by [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html). Quoting the javadoc:

> A data output stream lets an application write primitive Java data types to an output stream in a portable way. An application can then use a data input stream to read the data back in.

It is *not* for writing a .txt file. Use a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) for that.

Comment: @Thank you Andreas, now I understand this codes better under your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)--

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number1 = 45;
    double number2 = 10.3;
    String string = "a string";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("a");

    try {

      FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("M:\\saved.txt");

      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);

      out.write(((Integer)number1).toString());
      out.println();
      out.write(string);
      out.println();
      out.write(((Double)number2).toString());
      out.println();
      for (String string2 : list) {
        out.write(string2);

      }
      out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Simona; if given suggestion is working well; make sure to upvote or accept answer so that it will help other viewers -- if they face same kind of issue.